# Play mp3 file from Android file:///storage/emulated location

Tags: android, cordova

I have an android app written in cordova/ionic which has a requirement to show all music files in the device in a list. I am using cordova-file-plugin to recursively
load the music files. I am using cordovaNativeAudio plugin to play these files.
Some of these files are located in file:///storage/emulated/0/Ringtones/ 
But when i play these files using

```
$cordovaNativeAudio.play("test");
```

it is not playing. But the plugin works fine if the mp3 files are within the project (www/audio) folder.

Do i need special permissions to play the files outside the project ?
These are my current permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Do i need to transfer these files to my project to make it play?
 i tried both nativeURL and fullPath but to no avail.

nativeURL shows as "file:///storage/emulated/0/Ringtones/test.mp3"

fullPath shows as /Ringtones/test.mp3

**UPDATE**
This is the error in console : java.io.FileNotFoundException: www/file:///storage/emulated/0/Ringtones/test.mp3 
Thanks !